# How to avoid browser storing session data and credentials?

Tags: apache, google-chrome, session, authentication, session-cookies

I am running Apache web server with authentication enabled. When I am logged into a session, it seems by default when we open another tab, the session is being continued. I would like apache to ask me for credentials even when we open another tab in Chrome. How can we achieve this(basically I wouldnt want the browser to store my session credentials and data)? Is it configurable from the browser end or within apache settings?

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but I believe that sessionStorage is one of the few ways you can achieve tab-specific storage / cookies.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage